# Looping through array for Unity GameObjects for AutoSpawn

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, unity-game-engine, iteration

I'm trying to do the following. I have an array with 2 GameObjects in it. I made a script for auto spawning them following some examples and modifying the script for my preferences.(I'm almost there).

The thing is that the spawner spawns only 1 GameObject and then stops. I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong with loops, but I have 2 days now and can't figure it out. What I want is for the spawner to spawn the first GameObject 5 times and then go to the next GameObject and spawn it another 5 times, also I added a collision function from previous help so that the spawned GameObjects don't spawn inside walls, but for some reason it doesn't work well.

I have 2 box colliders on the GameObjects for different job, one is triggered and takes the whole GameObjects size and the other is little smaller to work as collider(not triggered), any suggestions or help? Here is the code I'm working on.

```
public GameObject[] objblabla;
private GameObject selectedObject; 
public int limit;
private float radius = 5f;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(SpawnObjects());
}

IEnumerator SpawnObjects()
{
    foreach (GameObject selectedObject in objblabla)
    {
        while (limit != 0)
        {
            Vector3 freePos = GetFreePosition();
            Instantiate(selectedObject, freePos, Quaternion.identity);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);
            limit--;
        }
    }
}

Vector3 GetFreePosition()
{
    Vector3 position;
    Collider[] collisions = new Collider[1];
    do
    {
        position = new Vector3(Random.Range(35.0f, 950.0f), 10.0f, Random.Range(35.0f, 950.0f));
    }
    while (Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc(position, radius, collisions) > 0);

    return position;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing confusing things when you are looping through the gameObjects array.

An array as the possibility to call the `.Lenght` to check his size, with this in mind you can easily do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < objblabla.Lenght; i++)
{
for(int j = 0; j < 5: j++)
{
Vector3 freePos = GetFreePosition();
        Instantiate(selectedObject, freePos, Quaternion.identity);
}}
```

In this way, you will spawn 5 times an object for each one of the arrays. Instead of using **selectedObject** I suggest using:

```
objblabla[i];
```

Inside the **for loop** in this way you will call the objects in the order, one at time

Comment: i think i tried that before and didn't worked thats why i posted.But let me try again and tell back the result.Ty for replying.

Comment: Put a variable for the size of the array, then declare the array of GameObjects with that size or use the size for the array @Kostas

Comment: Working like a charm.Ty a lot.When i tried the same i remebered now that it didn;t worked the first time because i had the codde in LateUpdate.

Comment: of course, it was not working! Good luck for the game :D @Kostas

Comment: really,you are a lifesaver.It was so simple and i couldn't figure it out.Maybe I need some break from coding.When you force thing they never works most of the times.Again ty.

Comment: I don't do anything with a "thank you"... give me the green tick of power and knowledge... ;) @Kostas